# Eclipse open cpp short cut

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I am using eclipse to program c++. I am in eclipse c++ perspective.

I want to be able to quickly jump to any cpp.

I use the command ctrl+shift+t to search, and it only brings up .h files to jump to, but no .cpp.

Is there a way to jump to .cpp files?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

You can go to the menu Navigate--Open Resource... and type in a part of .cpp file name. Usually this command has a shortcut ctrl+shift+r.